# How to know whether SSD is permanently implanted on Mac or not?

Tags: mac, ssd

I've heard that SSDs have a read and write limit.So,if my SSD is implanted on the logic board then I will need to get a new Mac.So how do I know if my SSD is removable via System Report or command line?

Comment: google the model from the about this mac window, for example "MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2015" and "replacement ssd" and that will, very quickly, tell you what you need to know. BTW it is unlikely your SSD will need to be replaced due to wear and tear,

Comment: I just found out that my Mac has a removable ssd.Model MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).But it shows as 'Fixed' in system report.@ Steve Chambers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MacBook that has one USB-C port and the TouchBar MBP are the only Mac going back to 2013 models where the main storage is soldered to the logic board. All the rest are serviceable without solder or needing a new serialized logic board.

That being said, Apple and certified repair agents will repair all Mac with storage issues for 5 years from the date of last sale of that model so practically, you’re never without repair options even if you don’t have the skill or tools or training to successfully close a Mac after repair.

*Just about anyone can go to ifixit.com and open up a Mac. The trick is getting the right parts, not damaging tiny screws and connectors and putting it all back together so the system is operational and reliable.*

Comment: Not true. The MBP w/ Touch Bar also have soldered storage (both 13” + 15”, both 2016 and 2017 models). https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Touch+Bar+Teardown/73395. The 13” MBP w/o Touch Bar does have a replaceable storage drive.

Comment: @NoahL Thanks for the comment. The TouchBar MBP have a storage module that is not soldered to the logic board. This is the same for Air, MacPro where you can replace the storage module without needing a new serialized logic board or a soldering iron to replace that module. Am I missing something on step 11 of the ifixit tear down that you are seeing?

Comment: scroll down to “Final Thoughts”. It states that the storage is soldered to the board in that section. In step 11, I don’t see any information except for fans. In step 9, the diagram points to “64 GB flash chips” which are visibly attached to the board.

Comment: @NoahL Those 64 GB flash store things other than the main storage. If you look at step 10 - iFixit author states “It's nice that Apple has kept their removable SSDs a first-out component, simplifying upgrades.” You can see the PCI like pins on the SSD storage board and the screw holes indicating it’s a non-soldered and replaceable component.

Comment: Are you sure we’re looking at the same page? This is a quote from the top: “We would still rather see a removable/upgradable SSD, especially in a machine targeted at pros”. I see that authors’ note on the page for the 13” w/o Touch Bar. See these two articles: https://www.macrumors.com/2016/11/25/apple-ssd-data-recovery-macbook-pro/ and https://www.macrumors.com/2016/10/28/new-macbook-pro-removable-ssd/

Comment: It's [**Touch Bar**](https://developer.apple.com/macos/touch-bar/), two words, not one word "TouchBar".